# What does AddressFamily.FireFox refer to in .NET sockets?

Tags: .net, firefox, networking

In System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily there are a number of obvious entries like  InterNetwork, AppleTalk and Ipx.  There's also one for "FireFox".  I assume this has nothing to do with the "Firefox" browser since a. it's cased differently and b. why would the Firefox browser have its own network address type.  So what the heck is this for?  Was there a FireFox network protocol?  I've googled around and searched wikipedia but any search for FireFox and network protocol gets, not surprisingly, thousands of hits for the Firefox browser.  I'm guessing this is a long-obsolete network protocol like Banyan Vines.

Can anyone enlighten me on what AddressFamily.FireFox is for?

Comment: I can tell it comes from Winsock2 API times, with a reference to 1996, so it's very likely a lot older than the web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was curious so I did some Googling around.  All of this is based on creative searching; not on any special knowledge that I have, so take it with a grain of salt.

FYI I'm new so I can only post one link, so URLs are included below the text.

Searching for Mark S. Edwards led me to this [mail archive](http://ftp.urz.uni-heidelberg.de/ftp/pub/net/winsock/winsock-l/faq+txt/winsock2.txt) (1), which gives the company as Firefox Communications Ltd.  Googling for that exact company name reveals a number of links to a product of theirs called [Novix](http://www.cbronline.com/news/firefox_takes_its_integrated_netware_servers_to_the_us_opens_in_seattle), which was apparently a [gateway](http://www.strom.com/pubwork/cwtcp93.html) (2) between NetWare IPX networks and the TCP/IP internet back in the day.  It seems that Novix had pretty good [Winsock integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20160517110129/http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/uw2nw.html) (3), which (I'm speculating) is where the `AF_FIREFOX` and `PF_FIREFOX` entries in winsock.h came from.  Since System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily is just a port of that old header file, the company lives on in Microsoft's massive set of supported, legacy APIs.

(1): `ftp.urz.uni-heidelberg.de/ftp/pub/net/winsock/winsock-l/faq+txt/winsock2.txt`

(2): `www.strom.com/pubwork/cwtcp93.html`

(3): `www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/uw2nw.html`

Comment: That first url is excellent, interesting, they are actually discussing using the pseudonym "localhost" when the machine's dns name isn't known and allocating the protocol numbers such as AF_FIREFOX and AF_IPX.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers I don't suppose you know a valid link to this, it appears the current one is dead.

Answer (score 0):

From [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers):

```
firefox         1689/tcp    firefox
firefox         1689/udp    firefox
#                           Mark S. Edwards <marke&firefox.co.uk>
```

Being that firefox.co.uk redirects to www.savecell.co.uk, I am guessing it is somehow related to thier product, or is a port that was to be used for a now defunct product/idea.

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to that as the address families are lower level, and include things like bluetooth, infra-red, etc. So far my best guess is it was a defunct internal protocol that never saw the light of day. If you check the winsock file, just below AF_FIREFOX is an entry AF_UNKNOWN1, so the winsock team at the time were not even sure what that one was for.